# Batch File to fill out fields on a website

Tags: batch-file

I'm brand new to both coding, and this website. After digging through search results here, I couldn't find the answer I'm looking for.

What I'm trying to do is create a batch file that will open a website (like gmail.com for example) and automatically fill in fields like the username and password ones.

I can get it to open the site, but I don't know how to get it to fill out the fields for me.

Is this even doable in .bat, or should I look elsewhere?

Finally, if you don't have the time to give me clear instructions, pointing me towards documentation that can would be highly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Can't be done with a batch-file. Look at using AutoIt or AutoHotKey

Comment: If you're doing stuff with websites, use Javascript. But it really depends on exactly what you're trying to do; a lot of sites (like Gmail) will save your credentials so you don't need to type anything.

Comment: @somethingdark Thank you very much for the input. This is mostly to streamline some log in procedures without using autofill.

Thank you both for the input, I'll look into your suggestions.